# regex join line infos

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse this package:

```
WGS AUFFUELLUNGEN
ADMIN1          23.03.
17:09   -20-   1500.00
17:10   JD20    560.00
17:11  -2.0-    112.00
ADMIN1          24.03.
14:51   JD50    500.00
ADMIN2          27.03.
08:58   JD50    500.00
----------------------
               3172.00
```

Parsing the user and date is easy:

```
\r?\n(.*)\s+(\d\d\.\d\d\.)
```

Parsing the time, denomination and amount is easy too:

```
\r?\n(\d\d:\d\d)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+\.\d\d)
```

But I need a parsing that detects user, date, time, denomination and amount for every booking at once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some kind of intermediate structure you can iterate over. If you cant change your java code maybe you can use a regex to first match a whole block of you example string. In a second step you match all the details.

```
public class RegexTestCase {

private static final String PACKAGE
  = "WGS AUFFUELLUNGEN     \n" +
    "ADMIN1          23.03.\n" +
    "17:09   -20-   1500.00\n" +
    "17:10   JD20    560.00\n" +
    "17:11  -2.0-    112.00\n" +
    "ADMIN1          24.03.\n" +
    "14:51   JD50    500.00\n" +
    "ADMIN2          27.03.\n" +
    "08:58   JD50    500.00\n" +
    "----------------------\n" +
    "               3172.00\n";

private static final String NL = "\\r?\\n";

private static final String USER_DATE_REGEX
 = "(.*?)\\s+(\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\.)";

private static final String TIME_AMOUNT_REGEX
 = "(\\d\\d:\\d\\d)\\s+(.*?)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d\\d)";

private static final String BLOCK_REGEX
  = USER_DATE_REGEX + NL + "((" + TIME_AMOUNT_REGEX + NL + ")+)";


@Test
public void testRegex() throws Exception {
    Pattern blockPattern = Pattern.compile( BLOCK_REGEX );
    Pattern timeAmountPattern = Pattern.compile( TIME_AMOUNT_REGEX );

    int count = 0;
    Matcher blockMatcher = blockPattern.matcher( PACKAGE );
    while (blockMatcher.find() ) {
        String name = blockMatcher.group( 1 );
        String date = blockMatcher.group( 2 );
        String block = blockMatcher.group( 3 );

        Matcher timeAmountMatcher = timeAmountPattern.matcher( block );
        while ( timeAmountMatcher.find() ) {
            String time   = timeAmountMatcher.group( 1 );
            String denom  = timeAmountMatcher.group( 2 );
            String amount = timeAmountMatcher.group( 3 );

            assertEquals( "wrong name", RESULTS[count].name, name );
            assertEquals( "wrong date", RESULTS[count].date, date );
            assertEquals( "wrong time", RESULTS[count].time, time );
            assertEquals( "wrong denom", RESULTS[count].denom, denom );
            assertEquals( "wrong amount", RESULTS[count].amount, amount );
            count++;
        }
    }
    assertEquals( "wrong number of results", 5, count);
}

private static final Result[] RESULTS
= { new Result("ADMIN1", "23.03.", "17:09", "-20-", "1500.00")
  , new Result("ADMIN1", "23.03.", "17:10", "JD20", "560.00")
  , new Result("ADMIN1", "23.03.", "17:11", "-2.0-", "112.00")
  , new Result("ADMIN1", "24.03.", "14:51", "JD50", "500.00")
  , new Result("ADMIN2", "27.03.", "08:58", "JD50", "500.00")
  };

static final class Result {
    private final String name;
    private final String date;
    private final String time;
    private final String denom;
    private final String amount;
    Result( String name, String date, String time, String denom, String amount ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.denom = denom;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the situation. The whole block (from headline to sum) is already parsed out of ~ 50 K text. To parse the details now is the challenge - to bring user, date, time, denomination, amount together for each booking with one expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your second regex is too eager, have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/yVTa5y/1).

I suggest to change it into `\r?\n(\d\d:\d\d)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+.\d\d)`

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/yVTa5y/3) would match user, date, time, denomination and amount for every booking at once, but I have added the multiline regex flag.:

```
(^(.*)\s+(\d\d\.\d\d\.)$|^(\d\d:\d\d)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+\.\d\d)$)+
```

Comment: Thx freedev, your expression does not work in our java tool or in online tools like https://regex101.com/

At the moment i try to learn more about the multiline option you mentioned...

Comment: Sorry, i missed setting the regex options. Nevertheless, i need that output format: 
Group 1 allways the user
Group 2 allways the date 
Group 3 allways the time
and so on

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the entire string by new line
2. Iterate over the each line and

   ```
     a. look for username and date by regex1, if matches then extract userName and Date
     b. if regex1 doesn't, then look for time, denomincation and amount regex2 . if it matches 
        then extract  time, denomination and amount from this.


   final String userRegex = "^(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.)$";
   final String timeRegex = "^(\\d+:\\d+)\\s+([\\S]+)\\s+(\\d+\\.?\\d+)$";
   ```

Sample Source:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String userRegex = "^(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.)$";
    final String timeRegex = "^(\\d+:\\d+)\\s+([\\S]+)\\s+(\\d+\\.?\\d+)$";

    final String string = "WGS AUFFUELLUNGEN\n"
            + "ADMIN1          23.03.\n"
            + "17:09   -20-   1500.00\n"
            + "17:10   JD20    560.00\n"
            + "17:11  -2.0-    112.00\n"
            + "ADMIN1          24.03.\n"
            + "14:51   JD50    500.00\n"
            + "ADMIN2          27.03.\n"
            + "08:58   JD50    500.00\n"
            + "----------------------\n"
            + "               3172.00\n";


    String[] list = string.split("\n");
    Matcher m;
    int cnt=1;
    for (String s : list) {
        m=Pattern.compile(userRegex).matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {

            System.out.println("##### List "+cnt+" ######");
            System.out.println("User Name:"+m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Date :"+m.group(2));
            cnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            m=Pattern.compile(timeRegex).matcher(s);
            if(m.matches())
            {
                System.out.println("Time :"+m.group(1));
                System.out.println("Denomination :"+m.group(2));
                System.out.println("Amount :"+m.group(3));
                System.out.println("---------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Rizwan. Unfornately i cannot code anything. I need one expression solving all bookings. I have to feed a java tool with that expression, that has a fix code.

Comment: That will suffice for any data of such format hence not fixed. Moreover, you can not get each individual data alone by a single regex in java as per your requirement goes !!